# create list using CustomSchemaXml from client object model

Tags: client-object-model, custom-list, list-definition

I'm using Client Object model of SharePoint 2010. What is the property CustomXmlScheme in list creation? MSDN say nothing about it. It seems not working. I'm using this code:

```
string xml = @"
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<List xmlns:ows=""Microsoft SharePoint"" Name=""t100"" Title=""t100"" Direction=""0"" BaseType=""1"">
  <MetaData>
    <Fields></Fields>
    <Views></Views>
    <Forms></Forms>
    <DefaultDescription>jdksjldj</DefaultDescription>
  </MetaData>
</List>";
var list = site.Lists.Add(new ListCreationInformation
                              {
                                  CustomSchemaXml = xml, 
                                  Title = "t035", 
                                  TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.Links
                              });
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How to make this code work? And that kind of properties i can use in CustomXmlScheme? Thanks.

Comment: What is happening other than not working? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sharepoint give me an error "Invalid list template". I'm trying set list properties like AllowDeletion and Flags, which is have't static typed field in client model. It possible to do from server OM, but is not appropriate for me :(